# Maximum number of MCSessions supported by iOS 8

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity, mcsession

I've read that the limit of `MCSession` is 8 devices. I intend to have a host device that creates many 1 to 1 connections with other devices. In this case, would the limit still be 7 connected devices, or can it have a larger number of `MCSession` instances?

If it matters, the host device is an iPad 4 with BLE, and communication would be purely over Bluetooth, there isn't any WIFI available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is 8 devices (including the host) per MCSession. But if you can have more than one MCSession, then you can have more device connected. Haven't tried it though.